# the function doesn't get a vector when getting a whole vector of objects

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, vector

the saveEverything function gets the User vector but not the Exercise vector (which is part of the User) and it doesn't transfer so I can't save the information to the file. What is it caused by?

[github link](https://github.com/Szymusiok/gym-app.git)

saveEverything function:

```
void saveEverything(std::vector<User> users){
std::fstream users_database;
users_database.open("users_database.txt",std::ios::out | 
std::ios::trunc);
if(!users_database)
    throw 1;
for(int i =0;i<users.size();i++){
    users_database<<users[i].getUserFirstName()<<"|" 
<<users[i].getUserLastname()<<"|"<<users[i].getUserAge()<<"|" 
<<users[i].getUserWeight()<<std::endl;
}
users_database<<"||ENDOFUSERS||"<<std::endl;

std::vector<Exercise> exercises;

for(int i=0;i<users.size();i++){
    users_database<<"||U||"<<std::endl;
    users_database<<users[i].getUserFirstName()<<"|" 
<<users[i].getUserLastname()<<std::endl;
    exercises = users[i].getExercises();
    for(Exercise exercise: exercises){
        users_database<<exercise.getExerciseName()<<"|" 
<<exercise.getExerciseWeight()<<"|"<<exercise.getExerciseSeries() 
<<"|"<<exercise.getExerciseReps()<<std::endl;
    }
    users_database<<"||END||"<<std::endl;
}

std::cout<<"Saving completed!"<<std::endl;
}
```

class User:

```
class User {
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const User 
&user);
private:
std::string UserFirstName;
std::string UserLastname;
unsigned int UserAge;
double UserWeight;

std::vector<Exercise>UserExercises;
```

getExercise() method:

```
std::vector<Exercise> User::getExercises(){
return UserExercises;
}
```

i tried to add copy contructors but they didn't work. Maybe you have an idea what is the reason or how else to save this information to the file?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] in your question, not as a link to external website.

Comment: It sounds like you mean `saveEverything` is not saving everything you expect to the file. Have you tried stepping through `saveEverything` in a debugger to see what is happening differently from what you expect?

Comment: There's nothing obviously incorrect about `saveEverything`. Maybe it's working fine and the bug is that the `UserExercises` vector is not getting populated because of a different bug. Have you considered that?

Comment: What does the copy constructor of `User` look like? Do you copy `UserExercises` as part of that (if not default)?

Comment: @MSpiller You are completely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` copy constructor is broken

```
User(const User &copy_user)
    : UserFirstName{copy_user.UserFirstName}, 
    UserLastname{copy_user.UserLastname}, UserAge{copy_user.UserAge}, 
    UserWeight{copy_user.UserWeight}{}
```

It fails to copy the `UserExercises` vector. This means that everytime you copy a `User` object you get an empty `UserExercises` vector.

One large benefit of using vectors and strings etc. is that you **don't** have to write copy constructors, assignment operators and destructors because the default ones do the right thing.

Just delete this bugged copy constructor, the default one is all you need.

I would also remove

```
~User()= default;
```

which is just wasted space and keystrokes.